# Document loader PDF is overlapping with the Status bar in the Xamarin forms iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, statusbar, overlapping

The document overlaps with the status bar when the screen navigates to open the URL with the document loader.
And we don't have control over the document screen. How to resolve it

```
    private async Task OnGoToTermsAndConditions()
    {
        DependencyService.Get<IOrientationInterface>().DisableRotation();

        if (CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.ToLower() == "fr")
            await _documentLoader.PreviewDocument(new Uri("https://MockURL/securefiles/TermsAndCondition_fr.pdf"), "TermsAndCondition.pdf");
        else
            await _documentLoader.PreviewDocument(new Uri("https://MockURL/securefiles/TermsAndCondition.pdf"), "TermsAndCondition.pdf");

        DependencyService.Get<IOrientationInterface>().EnableRotation();
    }
```

[image]

Here DONE button is over lapped with the time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to set the [Safe Area](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/page-safe-area-layout) like `ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"`?